# How to verify signature only one place in WCF RESTful service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing a WCF RESTfull interface,I am also writed a method to verify the access of invoker.My enviroment is:**C# + .NET framework 4.0 + WCF RESTful + Visual Studio 2013**. This is my verify code:

```
private bool CheckAuthorization()
{
    var ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
    var auth = ctx.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth) || auth != "123")
    {
       ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed;
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is my verify logic:

```
public string GetData(string a)
{
    if (!CheckAuthorization())
    {
        return "Access Failed!";
    }
    else
    {
        return "OK!You enter:" + a.ToString();
    }
}
```

And my question is:How to avoid write the verify code every function but only one place?I don't want to add **if (!CheckAuthorization())** in every function.My wcf program only have some *.svc file to provide Http request invoke.

Comment: you might be interested in a `Custom Http Module`.

Comment: OK,I am searching....，Thank you

Comment: Assuming your service is activated per request, you could possibly have this code in the wcf implementation class constructor.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Tt would be better,Thank you